# Extending jquery autocomplete :select part of string from inside text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='searchable'value='hello world' />
<input type='hidden' id=x value='hel' />
```

how can i select textfrom #searchable starting from end of value of hidden input till end of #searchable  ?

**Fixed thanks all**

```
    $('input.complete').live('keyup.autocomplete', function(){
        var hi=$(this).val().toUpperCase();
        var was=this;//PROBlEM was here... was=$(this)
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>ajax/ac',
                        data: { 'term': this.term,'page': 'clinic','key': this.element.attr('data-complete')},
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                            if(!data.length){
                                var result = [{label: 'No match found',value: response.term}];
                                response(result);
                            }else{
                                response(data);
                                $(was).val(data[0]['value']);
                                was.selectionStart=hi.length;
                                was.selectionEnd=data[0]['value'].length;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function(event, ui){},
                minLength: 2,
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you rolling out some kind of typeahead?

Comment: You mean you want to select `lo world`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté if thats what its called then yp :D!

Comment: Select or extract? This makes a whole lot of difference.

Comment: @ExplosionPills yp, so user if type more char its replaced, im trying to extend jquery autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
(function() {
    var search = $('#searchable')[0],
        searchvalue = search.value,
        xtext = $('#x').val(),
        startAt = searchvalue.indexOf(xtext) + xtext.length;
    search.selectionStart = startAt;
    search.selectionEnd = searchvalue.length;
}());
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qK6pq/3/show/)

If `x` value always start matching at the first character of search's value, the `searchvalue.indexOf(xtext)` is redundant as it will always return `0` and can be safely removed.

#### References:

- Dottoro: [`selectionStart`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php), [`selectionEnd`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljxjdqwh.php)
- MSDN: [`selectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`selectionEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- MDN: [`HTMLInputElement` Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties)

Note: As `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are part of HTML5, there's no IE < 9 support. If you're rolling out your own typeahead, I suggest feature testing these before applying the the autocomplete in the text input element if you plan to support old IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... tested in Firefox and Chrome...

This will highlight from the hidden value end to end of string:

```
$("#searchable")[0].selectionStart = $("#x").val().length;
$("#searchable")[0].selectionEnd = $("#searchable").val().length;
```

*This will highlight from start to hidden value:*

```
var s = $("#x").val();

$("#searchable")[0].selectionStart = 0;
$("#searchable")[0].selectionEnd = s.length;
```

Comment: i want to hightlight it not replace it

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany Which browser? What is the output?